# How to connect a SMB share with different users in Mac?

Tags: macos, smb, nas

I connect to some SMB shares with my own account (`my_own_account`), but I need to go to the same share with a different app account, since my account is not authorized to list what I want to see. I tried

Finder -> Go -> Connect to server -> `smb://the_other_account@myshare.mycompany.com`

It does not ask for a password, which is a sign of it does not use the account name to connect with. Then I saw that I was still connected to the share with `my_own_account`. I disconnect-eject the volume and try again but it does not change. I do not want to clear my credentials from the keychain because I use it frequently.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works when you try with **`:*`** after the account name.

`smb://the_other_account:*@myshare.mycompany.com`

The difference is the **`:*`** after the account name. It asks for the password. The weird thing is it shows `my_own_account` as connected but now I can see the folders that **the_other_account** is authorized to see.

Comment: Thank goodness for stackoverflow!